# How to correctly import a component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following component defined as below:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';

Vue.component('DatePicker', {
    template: `
    <datepicker name="date"></datepicker>
  `,
});
```

Which I am trying to import it from another file and use it in another component but for some reason I am getting error like:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option.

I am pretty new to Vue.js so I am wondering if someone can guide me what am I doing wrong here!

Here is how I am trying to use the component:

```
require('./datetime-picker');
<DatePicker></DatePicker>
```

Comment: Did you write `Vue.component('DatePicker' ....` before initialize Vue instance `new Vue({ ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register a component globally, try this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';

Vue.component('DatePicker', Datepicker);
```

Now you will be able use it by importing it into other components, without needing to use `components: { Datepicker }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any components inside a Vue.js template, you should declare that in `components` property of the component whoever is using it.

Make sure you add that as dependency in your component -

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';

Vue.component('DatePicker', {
    components: { Datepicker },
    template: `
    <datepicker name="date"></datepicker>
  `,
});
```

Comment: Most folks using Vue will use  modern syntax:  `components: { Datepicker },`